# SDL_BlitSurface() not displaying image?

Tags: c++, sdl

So I'm trying to display a simply image with the SDL library, but when I use the function SDL_BlitSurface() nothing happens, and all I get is a black screen. I should also note that I have the .bmp file, the source, and the executable file all in the same directory.

```
//SDL Header
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    //Starts SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    //SDL Surfaces are images that are going to be displayed.
    SDL_Surface* Hello = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* Screen = NULL;

    //Sets the size of the window (Length, Height, Color(bits), Sets the Surface in Software Memory)
    Screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    //Loads a .bmp image
    Hello = SDL_LoadBMP("Hello.bmp");
    //Applies the loaded image to the screen
    SDL_BlitSurface(Hello, NULL, Screen, NULL);
    //Update Screen
    SDL_Flip(Screen);
    //Pause
    SDL_Delay(2000);
    //Deletes the loaded image from memory
    SDL_FreeSurface(Hello);
    //Quits SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LoadBMP() is crap. Install SDL_image library

```
sudo apt-get install SDL_image SDL_image_dev
```

(not sure about the names of the packages. Just use aptitude or synaptic or whatever to find them)

and include it with

```
#include "SDL_image.h"
```

You load your image then with

```
SDL_Surface* Hello = IMG_Load("Hello.bmp");
if (!Hello){
    printf("Ooops, something went wrong: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
    exit(0);
}
```

**Important:** Note that you should always do an error check and print out the error.

`if (!Hello)` is the same as `if (Hello == NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried blitting any other types of images? when I first started SDL I remember having issues with .bmp files. Try a .jpg or .png and get back to me whether your code works or not.

Comment: Do you know what the function is to display a .jpg? SDL_LoadJPG()?

Comment: scrap what I said a minute ago -- your code works for me. You are probably missing the .dll files in your project.

Comment: That could be it. I'm on Ubuntu, do you know where the .dll is located there?

Comment: Wherever you but them I think haha. In Windows you manually move them to either your project directory or the sys64 folder. I'm assuming when you installed on Ubuntu you did the same, just different folder names. If not, find where your SDL folder is and get them from there. You need to put the .dll files in the same folder as your project executable.

Comment: Yea, I get that. But I installed SDL from the command line with "sudo apt-get install SDL...." So it placed the folders for me. Do you know where it installs to?

Comment: @ChristianGonzalez On Linux it should work fine. It's just Windows where you have to do such crap.

Comment: @tombom I was unaware installation was so simple on Linux. That makes is much easier for you christian.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar "Problems"; maybe it's a pre-Version, or version incompatible to your graphic-driver; let's figure out. SWSurface and Flip; as I remember, the Flip-functionality only works with double-buffered HW_Surface.

```
Screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
```

Please try Update instead of Flip.

```
SDL_Update(surface);
```

And nexttime :)

```
Hello = SDL_LoadBMP("Hello.bmp");
if(Hello != NULL) {
    //Applies the loaded image to the screen
    SDL_BlitSurface(Hello, NULL, Screen, NULL);
    //Update Screen
    ...
    //Deletes the loaded image from memory
    SDL_FreeSurface(Hello);
}
```

because `SDL_FreeSurface(NULL)` will crash your programm.

Comment: When `SDL_Flip` is called on a surface that is not double-buffered, it will automatically call `SDL_UpdateRect` internally. Hence, it should work on all video surfaces. In addition, `SDL_FreeSurface(NULL)` will not make your program crash (`SDL_FreeSurface` just returns when called with `NULL`).